# CSS selector combination for accessing nested divs

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the following HTML code

```
<div id="left">
  <div id="coverage">
    <h3>coverage</h3>
    <!-- first div -->
    <div>    
      <div>
        <span>left->coverage->div 1->inner div 1->span text</span>
      </div>

      <div>
        <span>left->coverage->div 1->inner div 2->span text</span>
      </div>      
    </div>

    <!-- second div -->
    <div>

      <!-- div to be accessed -->
      <div>
          <span>left->coverage->div 2->inner div 1->span text</span>
      </div>    

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to access the first div nested inside the second div.I tried this, but it didn't work

```
#left #coverage  div:first-child
{
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `nth-of-type()` to get second `div` and `:first-child` to get first div inside.

```css
#left #coverage > div:nth-of-type(2) div:first-child {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="left">
  <div id="coverage">
    <h3>coverage</h3>
    <!-- first div -->
    <div>
      <div>
        <span>left->coverage->div 1->inner div 1->span text</span>
      </div>

      <div>
        <span>left->coverage->div 1->inner div 2->span text</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- second div -->
    <div>

      <!-- div to be accessed -->
      <div>
        <span>left->coverage->div 2->inner div 1->span text</span>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I stop at `div:nth-of-type(2)` the output is not as i expected.
http://www.cssdesk.com/aFQV3

Answer (score 1):

`#left #coverage>div:nth-of-type(2)>div` should work for your purposes:

```css
#left #coverage>div:nth-of-type(2)>div {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="left">
  <div id="coverage">
    <h3>coverage</h3>
    <!-- first div -->
    <div>
      <div>
        <span>left->coverage->div 1->inner div 1->span text</span>
      </div>

      <div>
        <span>left->coverage->div 1->inner div 2->span text</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- second div -->
    <div>

      <!-- div to be accessed -->
      <div>
        <span>left->coverage->div 2->inner div 1->span text</span>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```